# Can anyone explain the technicality of zspace AR-VR product and how it works?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, virtual-reality, google-vr

I just came to know about a AR-VR company for educational interactive content. I know about Augmented reality apps which can be developed using Unity framework and know Virtual reality too.

But can anyone try to explain how they are doing it or any idea or direction will be helpful?

Can we use existing Google cardboard and some tool to interact with the 3D object? Like this - [DIY hand tracking VR controller.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l5pMsS43Pbo)

Thanks in advance and let me know if you guys have more questions.

Answer (score 0):

After a quick look at the [official documentation](http://cdn.zspace.com/downloads/documentation/developer/zSpace_Developer_Intro_v1.0_rev1.2.pdf): it looks like the Z Space system is a 3d display (working like NVidia 3dVision or any some 3d television sets) with head tracking (to render in correct perspective) and a 3d-tracked stylus for interaction.
**TL;DR:** It's a 3D VR-like portal through a laptop screen.

Cardboard controllers won't work with it and would be completely redundant because of the stylus.